# How to Use sqldependency for each seprate query and raise different event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, sqldependency

May be this question will be duplicate but I'm unable to find. I'm using signalR and sqldependency for my application. I've performed one query operation successfully. but will i write separate sqldependency code for every query. sqldependency code is on application level or is separate for each query.

1) how to use different query for each operation?

2) how to call different onchange event

```
 public void RegisterNotification()
    {   string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FFFConnention"].ConnectionString;

        //We have selected the entire table as the command, so SQL Server executes this script and sees if there is a change in the result, raise the event
     // how to use different query for each operation
        string commandText = @"
                                Select
                                dbo.Notification.UserName
                                From dbo.Notification                                     
                                ";

        //Start the SQL Dependency
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command);

                NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub();
                //how to call different onchange event
                sqlDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(hub.sqlDependency_OnChange);

                // NOTE: You have to execute the command, or the notification will never fire.
                command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
    }
```